# "zwar noch" - meaning of idiom

Tags: meaning, idiom

What does "**zwar noch**" imply in the below sentence:

> "Man sieht sich nun sozusagen blind an dem objectiven Ergebnis, an dem Object, das **zwar noch** als vernünftig, ideenerfüllt gedacht wird, während doch das Subject und das subjective Denken, wovon es ausgegangen ist, vergessen wird."

Would the meaning be any different if one just deleted "zwar noch" and instead wrote:
"Man sieht sich nun sozusagen blind an dem objectiven Ergebnis, an dem Object, das als vernünftig, ideenerfüllt gedacht wird, während doch das Subject und das subjective Denken, wovon es ausgegangen ist, vergessen wird."?

Comment: I am not sure this question is about a specific [tag:idioms].

Comment: *zwar noch* combines *zwar* and *noch*, it's as simple as that.

Comment: Can you please provide the source? This sounds like a somewhat old philosophic text. I'd generally discourage German learners from reading them since they use quite unusual words and phrasing and not even educated native speakers usually understand them without seriously studying the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the meaning would change a bit, if the **zwar noch** was deleted. Even not an exact translation, the closest translation of **zwar noch** would be *albeit still*. It expresses that the result/object ist *still* considered reasonable, while the original thinking/subject it is based on, is forgotten.
The change is not a drastic one, it is more on a subtle emphasis-level (and would make the style a bit more rugged).